# How Does SQL Server Management Server Authenticate

Tags: sql-server

When using SQL Server Management Studio and logging in as a Windows User, does the Studio authenticate against AD again, or will it use the Windows information?

The reason why I ask is if a user logs into Windows and then their permissions change for the database for access. When they run the studio, will they have the access they need? Or will they have to log off completely to Windows?

Answer (score 0):

The depends on how the permissions on the database have been granted.

When a domain user logs into a Windows console, their login session contains the list of group memberships that were valid at the time of login.  If they are added to a new group after logging in, they won't actually get the benefits of that group membership *on that computer* until after they logout and log back in.

So...

- If the security [ACE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374868(v=vs.85).aspx) on the database object references the user directly, they will not need to logout and back in for the change to take effect.
- If the security [ACE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374868(v=vs.85).aspx) on the database object references a group that the user was already a member of when they logged in, they will not need to logout and back in for the change to take effect.
- If the security [ACE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374868(v=vs.85).aspx) on the database object references a group that the user was not a member of when they logged in (because they were added later), they **will** need to logout and back in for the change to take effect.

Comment: Log out/in is *sufficient*, but is it *necessary*? That is, would a `klist purge` or similar do the trick?

Comment: I've never tested in depth. So I personally can't say for sure.